# Benchmarking of Hyperledger fabric with Caliper (if fabric architecture is changed)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-caliper

I have made some changes to the fabric architecture (let's call it "myversion" of fabric) and now I want to check the tps of a network deployed on "myversion" with caliper. Is it possible to do so? And, if yes, how would I make caliper to use "myversion", in place of fabric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the official sdk is still compatible with the custom fabric, then we just have to point caliper to the endpoints of the deployed network. If you broke the API, then you'll have to write your own adapter for your new platform.

Here is the link to the same:
https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/caliper?msg=EhTjHNuvjtsqimBzF